# Delete a div using "this" with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, this

What I would like to do is to create a div by clicking on a button. In that div there will be another button if clicked will delete the div that it is in. So potentially the first button will create many div's with this delete button inside but I want the delete button to only delete the div that it is within. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just write the code to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not need to keep the "delete button" on your page, bind the `click` event on each of them and use `.removeChild` on the parent element of the parent div. 
[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KZm9u/5/)

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work in Firefox or IE because the proper DOM method (which you need to call on the parent of the object you want to remove) is `.removeChild()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<script>

var addDiv = (function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode('some text'));

  var button = document.createElement('button');
  button.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Remove...'));
  button.type = "button";


  return function() {
    var d = div.cloneNode(true);
    var b = button.cloneNode(true);
    b.onclick = function() {
      var d = this.parentNode;
      d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
    };
    d.appendChild(b);
    document.body.appendChild(d);
  };
}())

</script>

<button onclick="addDiv()">Add a div</button>
```

The above is just a trivial example to demonstrate one way to go about it. Note that if you clone an element, listeners added as properties or by addEventListener are dropped (this script would be very much simpler if they weren't).

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id='create' value="Create div!"/>
```

JS:

```
var i = 0;
document.onclick = function(e) {
    var t = e.target;
  if(t.id == 'create'){
     t.parentNode.innerHTML += '<div>I AM A CHILD '+(++i)+' <input type="button" class="child" value="DELETE ME!"/><br/></div>';
    }
  if (t.className == 'child') {
    t.parentNode.outerHTML = '';
  }
};
```

using document.onclick and detecting the target element can be used as a live click to monitor newly created divs.

Its early and my brain may be a little foggy and the code may be a little dirty

Here is a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KZm9u/10/)**